# HTML linking to a level inside current route

Tags: html, anchor

I am trying to do a relative anchor to a level inside the current route but can't seem to figure it out. For example, if I am in the following route: `http://domain.com/first/second` how could I do a relative link from there to: `http://domain.com/first/second/third`?

- `<a href="third">` takes me to `http://domain.com/first/third`
- `<a href="./third">` also takes me to `http://domain.com/first/third`
- `<a href="/third">` takes me to `http://domain.com/third`

The only way I've found is by using either `second/third` or `./second/third` which I'm hesitant to use because I might need the same view from another route and `second` might be something else. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: the last part *'second' is treated as file*. so all anchor paths are relative to the folder i.e. `first/`. you either use a trailing slash `/` in your url or use 'second/third' relative path in your anchor

Comment: I guess I'll have to deal with it server-side.

Comment: You can use JavaScript:

    <a href="javascript:window.location=document.URL+'/subaddress'">Go deeper</a>